# Help Finding Closed Form for Function of Decreasing Half Steps

Tags: summation, closed-form

I would like to know if there is a closed form for this function:

$ 
f(x) = 
    \begin{cases}
      \frac{1}{2}, & \text{if}\ 0 \leq x < \frac{1}{2} \\
      \frac{1}{4}, & \text{if}\ \frac{1}{2} \leq x < \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} \\
      \frac{1}{8}, & \text{if}\ \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} \leq x < \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{8} \\
      \frac{1}{16}, & \text{if}\ \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{8} \leq x < \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{16} \\
...
    \end{cases}
$

[Image of function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BpOn4.jpg)

Comment: I don't agree to close this question : the OP has spend time carefully Latex typing his question and providing a graphical representation. It is understandable that he/she has no idea how to tackle such a question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

*Fig. 1: Graphical representation of function $f$ (formula (0)). The red vertical segments are a plotting artefact.*

Here is a solution:

$$y=f(x)=2^{\lfloor\log_2(1-x)\rfloor}\tag{0}$$

where $\lfloor \cdots \rfloor$ is the floor function and $\log_2$ is the logarithm function with base $2$.

**Remark:** Consideration of the extreme cases of the "integer part of $a$", which can be $a$ or $a-1$, one gets

- 1. $ \ \ y=2^{\log_2(1-x)}=1-x$ or
- 2. $ \ \ y=2^{\log_2(1-x)-1}=\tfrac12 (1-x)$

which are the equations of the lines containing resp. the "upper" and "lower" points of discontinuity of the graphical representation (dotted blue lines in the figures).

**Proof of formula (0):**

[image]

*Fig. 2: Graphical representation of function $g$, given by formula (1), related to function $f$ by $f(x)=g(1-x)$.*

In fact, it will be equivalent and simpler to work on function $g$ with graphical representation given in Fig. 2 and establish that its equation is

$$y=g(x)=2^{\lfloor\log_2(x)\rfloor}\tag{1}$$

Function $g$ is defined as taking values $$y=\tfrac{1}{2^{n+1}}\tag{2}$$ for

$$\tfrac{1}{2^{n+1}} < x \le \tfrac{1}{2^{n}}\tag{3}$$

**Remark:** $g$ is in fact a rather [well known function](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1310371) giving the highest power of 2 smaller than or equal to a given number $x$.

Let us attempt to express $n$ as a function of $x$.

Applying the increasing function  $\log_2$ to this double inequation, we get:
$$-(n+1) < \log_2(x) \le -n$$ or, reversing the sign and the direction of inequalities:
$$n \le -\log_2(x) < n+1$$
Otherwise said: $$n=\lfloor -\log_2(x) \rfloor.$$
Plugging this expression of $n$ into relationship (2) gives:
$$y=2^{-(n+1)}=y=2^{-\lceil -\log_2(x) \rceil}$$
which is equivalent to expression (1) (where $\lceil...\rceil$ is the "ceiling" function).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I think I now have a better understanding of how to approach a problem like this.

Comment: I have discovered that function $g$ is used elsewhere: see for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1310371) and in particular the answer by Martin Sleziak. See also the nice characterisation by a functional equation [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2236916).